# How to let div inherit the width and height of the browser window

Tags: html, css

Before I ask, I am telling you that I am really a newbie on css. I have been thinking that css and I won't get really along well (Just kidding!) Anyway, my question I think is really simple but I cannot really find a way to let my style act as it should be.

I wanted to have a two-column layout. The left column is fixed on size and the other is fluid. I only want to have it inherit the viewport of the browser window in terms of height and width. I tried adding `height:100%;` on almost all of my divs but I cannot make it work. Indeed, a total newbie.

I have set up a fiddle to let you look about what my total-newbie-scenario.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KLKn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there! You forgot to declare the `height: 100%;` on the body **and** the html tag.

Since you only declared it on the `body` tag it has no idea what 100% height is since it's parent, `html`, has no set height.

Here is the css I changed:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#maincontainer {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/5KLKn/1/)

I would also suggest improve the structure of your html.

Here is a fiddle to show how to clean up your structure, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/7PnUy/).

Comment: wow! I sure missed that out! (Or did I think about that?) Thanks Josh!

Comment: lol no problem and best of luck in your design! Just remember that each parent of that element must have 100% height for the child to base it's height off of.

Comment: I am really working this styling thing out. lol. Thanks also for cleaning my html. @Josh Powell

Comment: No problem and it just takes time to learn all of the tips and tricks, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

to make a div's height 100% to window height,  you should set body and html height to 100%. then set their children to 100% to make them take the whole height of window..

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```